# Bash script - unix - command not found

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

I am new to bash script and I wonder why I recieve the above message. I try to an arithmetic value which comes from the for loop and then I would like to print the array. Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance!!

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a SCORES
for j in `seq 0 5`;
do
SCORES$j="$(sh myscript.sh $DSLAM $j | grep "" -c )"
done
for k in "${SCORES[@]}"
do
    echo "message $'\t' $SCORES$k"
done
echo ${#SCORES}
```

=======

Output

```
abcd.sh: line 16: SCORES0=3: command not found
abcd.sh: line 16: SCORES1=135: command not found
abcd.sh: line 16: SCORES2=826: command not found
abcd.sh: line 16: SCORES3=107: command not found
abcd.sh: line 16: SCORES4=3: command not found
abcd.sh: line 16: SCORES5=3: command not found
0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign variable with name, which is generated at run time; at least not the way you are trying.

You have below options:

```
declare "SCORES$j=$(sh myscript.sh $DSLAM $j | grep '' -c )" # creates new variables like SCORES1, SCORES2 etc.

eval "SCORES$j=$(sh myscript.sh $DSLAM $j | grep '' -c )" #Definitely not preferred.

SCORES[$j]="$(sh myscript.sh $DSLAM $j | grep '' -c )" #uses array you have created.
```

Most likely, option 3 is what you want.

Comment: Using `eval` is only necessary in POSIX shell, which has neither arrays nor the `declare` command. You should not even consider using it for this purpose in `bash`.

Comment: ^^ I agree.. @chepner: About the edit: Is it really required? I think, double quotes inside `$()` do not act as the closing double quotes for double quotes started at `declare "`... try `declare "t=$(seq 1 20 | grep "2")"; echo "$t"`

Comment: ^^ http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048 Or just google for "bash eval is evil" you would find more examples. In nutshelll, `eval` opens up the possibility of [code injections](http://xkcd.com/327/). My bad... I should not have suggested the bad practice in first place.